# Two servers with same name on different networks

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share

I'm currently having a problem with Windows shares and two Windows Server 2008 R2 servers on different networks with the same name.

I have on one network a server called "Server" @ domain1 with the IP 192.168.0.201, which has my company's shares, and on the other network a server called "Server" @ domain2 with the IP 10.11.12.250. I have my shares configured like "\\Server\share".

The problem is, when I take my laptop to the other network on domain2 and then come back to domain1, apart from me having problems accessing "Server@domain2", when I try to access the shares I have created, it gives me permission errors on some folders (not all).

Accessing directly through IP I have no problems at all.

I'm using Windows 7 Professional and my computer is registered on domain1.

Any thoughts?

Thank you,
André.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

- use the FQDN of each server instead of just the host name. (assuming DNS resolution is done properly).
- use the server's IP address instead of the server name
- add an alias (with a different host name) in your local DNS server that points to the remote server's IP address.
- add an entry (with a different host name) in your local HOST file that points to the remote server's IP address.

Comment: I would also add about checking the credential manager as there maybe cached credentials that are not shared against either servers. (Control Panel->Credential Manager->Windows Credentials)

Comment: Thank you Wayne, that was the problem, I had configured the domain2 user for "Server", explains the permission problems back on domain1. Thank you also Stephane for the alternatives, I opted to configure the shares with IP.